# Do 404 and 403 errors listed in Google Search Console affect SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, 404, ranking, 403-forbidden, angular.js

I'm prerendering a Angular app for SEO. When I check in the webmaster tool, there are a few hundred 404 and 403 errors. Will this affect my SEO ranking?

Comment: No. Just do not link to those pages. ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/RMjFPCSs5fm

Answer (score 2):

No, they only hurt feelings and at most times require you to either go crazy trying to figure it out, or have to explain to a client why they exists.

Either way it is best to know at least why you are getting the errors, if indeed those pages should be showing up.